# How to show partial key in UML ER diagram

Tags: sql, uml, diagram, entity-relationship

In Chen's notation partial keys (*discriminator*) were shown as *dashed lines*, how are they shown in **UML** ER (entity-relationship) diagram?

Comment: or is it correct to just declare partial keys of a table as primary keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly UML leaves that at your discretion and does not discriminate between partial keys and other composite keys (the difference between weak and strong entities is less pronounced in E-R or UML).

Comment: that is correct, one does not need to explicitly show the partial key in uml. although there exists a <<weak>> identifier, i have never seen it used.